# Updating SSD firmware in old Macbooks

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd, firmware

I'm upgrading the HDD in a MacBook7,1 (the white 13" unibody one) to a SSD.

I read somewhere that it's important to be able to update SSD firmware, but that some SSD makers don't offer update software that runs on Mac OS.

What's the story with this? Is operating system support for firmware updates an actual problem, and if so how can I tell which SSDs are Mac-friendly?

Comment: There's a very long & sorry tale here http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/151974/how-to-upgrade-firmware-and-reperform-a-samsung-840-evo-on-a-mac/170145#170145 the end result being to... clone the drive, format NTFS, put it in a PC, update/reperform. Put it back in the Mac, format HFS+, clone back.

Comment: @Tetsujin fortunately I have a CD drive in this machine. Think I'll be OK then? I was probably going to get the EVO 840

Comment: I think your advantage getting one now, is it will likely already have the firmware update that was needed to solve the performance problems initially, so you might never need to do it. I had to do mine the NTFS in a PC route, no other way would work for me.

Comment: @Tetsijun I wondered the same thing. As frustrating as your experience must have been, I have to say I'm glad you were able to figure out all the alternatives and post them here. Now you're an expert!

Comment: Thank you - to be honest, the research took longer than the actual task eventually. It was a nuisance to have to clone the drive & move it over to a PC, but it wasn't *actually* difficult, just a task I could have easily lived without ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a CD drive, you can update the firmware of Samsung's Sold State Drives (SSD). Samsung [provide bootable disk images](http://www.samsung.com/global/business/semiconductor/minisite/SSD/global/html/support/downloads.html) to update an SSD drive installed within a Mac:

> ### Samsung SSD Firmware Updates for Mac Users
>
> Below you will find the latest firmware downloads for recent Samsung-branded SSDs. 
>   ISO files may be used only via DOS using a bootable CD/DVD.
>
> … 840 EVO, 840 PRO, 840, 830 Series, and 470 Series …

The process is not friendly but it works. The disk image needs to be burnt to a CD, then you boot your Mac from the disc. The updating process takes seconds and is not complex.

The disc contains a cut down edition of Linux. The result is a text based interface:

[image: Top of the screen running Samsung's updater]

I recently applied the 840 EVO update and while my update was not destructive, you **must back-up** first. The update process explicitly warns that it could wipe the drive.

Comment: Yeah, one of the many alternatives I tried at the time - never got it to work, unfortunately.

Comment: Great. Is there a simple way to check whether I need the upgrade or not? I _think_ I have blank CDs but I don't want to buy a 5 pack and have them go to waste.

Comment: Sadly, I could not find an easy way to check the installed version.